# Using RegEx to extract a string in a URL

Tags: regex

I've tried to search for this and I'm sure versions of this question have been asked, but I haven't been able to apply other answers to my case.

I need to use RegEx to extract a random string of characters and symbols that appears in the URL when an advertiser sends traffic to me.

The referring URL looks something like this, with the part I want to extract in bold:

```
https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click%**long-string-of-characters-and-symbols**https://www.mywebsite.com
```

That long string of characters and symbols (the hash) contains multiple % signs so I need the entire string after the first % sign, but before my website's URL.

I've been pulling my hair out on this and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So basically you need a substring between two known strings?  Why is this a problem?

Comment: Did you try `%(.*)https:\/\/www.mywebsite.com`? Also, you should be aware that there are many flavours of regex, so it can be important to tell us what language it is being used in, e.g. JavaScript, .NET, or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
(?<=%).*(?=https)
```

How it works:

- `(?<=%)` Positive lookbehind: search for a character preceeded by `%`
- `.*` matches everything until...
- `(?=https)`: the first `https` occurs (Positive lookhead)

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thanks for the explanation for each group -- very helpful!